# Creating a survey in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm new to Flask so was hoping for some help as I've hit a road block.

Objective: I need users to be able to login and complete a survey every two weeks. It will be the same survey they complete and I need to be able to distinguish which survey was completed in week1, week2 etc. Each user will complete the survey on a different date as it is two weeks from when they join rather than everyone completing a survey on the exact same date.

My current thought process: I have created one class for User and one class for Survey in my models.py and connected them with a db.relationship() column. I have a wtf-form that the user fills in (fields correspond to attributes in the survey class). Here's the code if it helps:

```
from project import db,login_manager
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin
from datetime import datetime


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    #columns of database
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    survey = db.relationship('Survey', backref='respondee', lazy=True)

    def __init__(self, email, username, password):
        self.email= email
        self.username = username
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Username {self.username}"



class Survey(db.Model):

    users = db.relationship(User)

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    # what the respondee needs to provide when completing the questionnaire (not finished as I'm waiting on the actual questions at the moment
    def __init__(self, user_id, )
```

This probably isn't the right logic but I'm not sure what the best way is.

Would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction regarding:

1. Am I correct in thinking that the Survey() class columns should mirror the Flask form questions
2. Given that the same survey is going to be completed every two weeks by users, what's the best way to differentiate when each survey was completed. Users will be completing the survey on different dates as it's two weeks from when they join.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You are already saving the creation datetime of each survey in Survey.date. You just need to add an identical field to User to save the creation time of each user. You can then perform simple date arithmetic to find out which two week time point each survey corresponds to.

```
days_since_registration = (survey.date.date() - user.date.date()).days
weeks_since_registration = round(days_since_registration / 7.0)
```